# Renombrar archivo en google drive usando la api php

Tags: php, google-api, google-drive

tengo la siguiente situación, estoy usando la api de google drive php para cambiar el nombre de un archivo pero me esta enviando el siguiente error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function patch() on null in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/cnombre/gdriver/configDrive.php:171 Stack trace: #0 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/cnombre/index.php(134): renameFile(Object(Google_Client), '1oRgT6IF459o3dI...', 'Prueba-10022021...') #1 {main} thrown in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/cnombre/gdriver/configDrive.php on line 171

La linea 171 esta dentro de la siguiente función la cual tome de la ayuda de google drive [Ir a
la ayuda de dirve](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/patch):

```
function renameFile($service, $fileId, $newTitle)
{
    try {
        $file = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
        $file->setName($newTitle);

        $updatedFile = $service->files->patch($fileId, $file, array( //Linea del error
            'fields' => 'title'
        )); 
        return $updatedFile;

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        print "An error occurred: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

De esta forma realizo la autenticación de cliente

```
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

/**
 * Returns an authorized API client.
 * @return Google_Client the authorized client object
 */
function getClient()
{
    $fileCredetials = "gdriver/credentials.json";
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName('Google Drive API PHP Quickstart');
    $client->setScopes(Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE);
    $client->setAuthConfig($fileCredetials);
    $client->setAccessType('offline');
    $client->setPrompt('select_account consent');

    // Load previously authorized token from a file, if it exists.
    $tokenPath = 'gdriver/token.json';
    if (file_exists($tokenPath)) {
        $accessToken = json_decode(file_get_contents($tokenPath), true);
        $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);
    }

    // If there is no previous token or it's expired.
    if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
        // Refresh the token if possible, else fetch a new one.
        if ($client->getRefreshToken()) {
            $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
        } else {
            // Request authorization from the user.
            $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
            printf("Open the following link in your browser:\n%s\n", $authUrl);
            print 'Enter verification code: ';
            $authCode = trim(fgets(STDIN));

            // Exchange authorization code for an access token.
            $accessToken = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($authCode);
            $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);

            // Check to see if there was an error.
            if (array_key_exists('error', $accessToken)) {
                throw new Exception(join(', ', $accessToken));
            }
        }
        // Save the token to a file.
        if (!file_exists(dirname($tokenPath))) {
            mkdir(dirname($tokenPath), 0700, true);
        }
        file_put_contents($tokenPath, json_encode($client->getAccessToken()));
    }
    return $client;
}
```

Y así estoy llamando las librerías de api para usarla:

```
$service = getClient();

$result = renameFile($service,'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX','Prueba-10.txt');
print_r($result);
```

Nota: el error solo se me esta produciendo con el método patch() con el resto no tengo problema.
Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu código tiene tres problemas.

Primero, el error `Call to a member function patch() on null in` significa que la propiedad `files` no existe en el valor que corresponde a `$service`. Esto se debe a que `$service` es una instancia autenticada del cliente pero sin ningún servicio. Hay que agregarle el servicio de la siguiente manera:

`$service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);`

Una vez haciendo eso, vas a encontrarte con otro error: 
`Call to undefined method Google_Service_Drive_Resource_Files::patch()`

El segundo error se deberá a que el método `patch` no existe en la propiedad `files`. El método correcto a usar es `update`; Y el tercer error es que la propiedad "title" sólo existe en la versión dos de la api de drive. Si estás usando la librería más reciente, `title` debe ser reemplazo por `name`. De modo que tu código tendrá que ser:

```
$authClient = getClient();
$service = new Google_Service_Drive($authClient);    
$result = renameFile($service,'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX','Prueba-10.txt');
print_r($result);
```

Y dentro da la función `renameFile()`, esto:

```
$updatedFile = $service->files->update($fileId, $file, array(
  'fields' => 'name'
));
```

Comment: Hola, gracias por contestar hice la corrección que me comento y me esta generando el siguiente error ahora ** Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function update() on null in **

Comment: En realidad no haz hecho la corrección más importante,asegurarte de que en realidad estés pasando una instancia del cliente autenticado en el valor de `$service`. Ese es tu mayor problema.

Comment: Hice una actualización en mi pregunta para ver si es esto lo que ud me comenta del `$service`   Gracias

Comment: Listo, ya vi donde estaba el error. Vuelve a leer la respuesta.

Comment: Muchas gracias ya me quedo.